# Show that $y''+(y^2+2y'^2-1)y'+y=0$ has a periodic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I made the following system
$$x'=y$$
$$y'=-(x^2 + 2y^2-1)y-x$$

The only critical point is $(0,0)$. I can get eigenvalues $\lambda = \frac{1\pm \sqrt3 i }{2}$. Then what should I do? Poincare-Bendixon theorem or whatever? I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for some invariant sets by taking the derivative of the function $\rho(x(t),y(t))=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$. It seems that $x^2+2y^2-1=0$ is an invariant set. Then you should try to apply P-B theorem.

Comment: Why is it invariant set? Then I am sorry I don't know how to apply.